# Invoke a components function from another in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

There are two component one display total price and other has shipping method. These are implemented on the cart checkout page. When I change the shipping method. It needs to be reflected on on the total price of checkout component.

The following component displays the total price
Here totalAmountWithDisocunt is the total price which need to be changed when shipping component radio button is selected
check-out-product.component.ts

```js
 
 
 import { Router,ActivatedRoute  } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'checkout-products',
  templateUrl: './check-out-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./check-out-products.component.css']
})
export class CheckOutProductsComponent implements OnInit {
   
  totalAmountWithDisocunt = 0;
  constructor(public http: Http, public configz: ConfigService,
  public shared: DataService  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.orderDetail = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.shared.orderDetails)));
    this.products = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.shared.cartProducts)));
    console.log(this.orderDetail);
    this.calculateTotal();
     
    }
  calculateDiscount = function () {
    var subTotal = 0;
    
    this.productsTotal = subTotal;
    this.discount = (subTotal - total);  
  };

   
  calculateTotal = function () {
    let a = 0;
    for (let value of this.products) {
       
      var subtotal = parseFloat(value.total);
      a = a + subtotal;
    }
   
    let b =  (this.orderDetail.tt);
    let c =  (this.orderDetail.shipping_cost );
    this.totalAmountWithDisocunt = a;
      
    this.calculateDiscount();
  };
}
```

check-out-product.component.html

```html
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table oxy-full-width oxy-card-order__summary-table">
                                                 
                                                
                                               
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Subtotal</td>
                                                        <td>  {{productsTotal| currencyChange}}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td>Tax</td>
                                                        <td> {{orderDetail.total_tax| currencyChange}}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Shipping</td>
                                                        <td>{{orderDetail.shipping_cost| currencyChange}}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Total</td>
                                                        <td>{{totalAmountWithDisocunt| currencyChange}}</td>
                                                    </tr>
```

The following is for shipping method component.When a radio button is clicked shipping method is selected and setMethod is called which should set the shipping price in above component.

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'shipping-methods',
  templateUrl: './shipping-methods.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shipping-methods.component.css']
}) 
export class ShippingMethodsComponent implements OnInit {
 
  shippingMethod  ;
  selectedMethod = true;

  constructor(public http: Http,public configz: ConfigService,
  public shared: DataService ) { 
   }
  
  setMethod(data) {
    
    this.selectedMethod = false;
    this.shared.orderDetails.shipping_cost = data.rate;
    this.shared.orderDetails.shipping_method = data.name + '(' + data.shipping_method + ')';
    console.log(this.shared.orderDetails);
  }
 
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
  
     <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text" >
         <p>Shipping Methods</p>
          <div  *ngFor="let m of shippingMethod">
                                                <h5  class="mdl-typography--title mdl-typography--font-light">{{m.name}}</h5 >

                                                <p   *ngFor="let s of m.services"  >

                                                    <label  class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="{{s.name}}">
                                                        <input  type="radio" id="{{s.name}}" [value]="s" (click)="setMethod(s)" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options"  checked />
                                                        <span class="mdl-radio__label">{{s.name+' ---- '+s.rate+' '+s.currencyCode}}
                                                </span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </p>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Now these are used on checkout page

```html
 <checkout-products></checkout-products>
                                            <shipping-methods></shipping-methods>
```

When I change the shipping methods then checkout price does not changes

Comment: This is a LOT of code. It would be easier if you only pasted the relevant code for the problem instead of half your app...

Comment: @masterfloda Edited

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Four ways : you can use which ever easy!

1. using event emitter

   ```
    @Output() shipmentInfoEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
   ```

   and when there is changes you can emit data

   ```
   this.shipmentInfoEmitter.emit(data);
   ```

   and you can consume by

   ```
   this.yourService.shipmentInfoEmitter.subscribe(user => this.updateUser(user));
   ```
2. Talk to parent using @Input & @Output

   ```
   <parent>
     <checkout-products [update]="callParent($event)">
     </checkout-products>
   <shipping-methods [change]="products"></shipping-methods>
   ```

shipment method changes pass to parent and parent push to checkout details

3. Use same service for storing this information
4. Use Redux/ngrx

Answer (score 0):

Use a service. It looks like your `DataService` is provided globally and used in both components to store the `orderDetails`. Just move your calculation methods there and you can use `this.shared.calculateTotal()`.

Alternatively, you can make the `orderDetails` in `DataService` an Observable (I'd suggest `rxjs/BehaviorSubject`). You can subscribe to it in `CheckOutProductsComponent`'s `ngOnInit`.

**DataService**

```
orderDetailsObservable: BehaviorSubject<OrderDetailsInterface> = new BehaviorSubject(this.orderDetails);
```

**CheckOutProductsComponent**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.shared.orderDetailsObservable.subscribe(
        next => {
                this.orderDetail = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(next)));
                this.calculateTotal();
            }
        );
    }
```

**ShippingMethodsComponent**

```
setMethod(data) {    
    this.selectedMethod = false;
    // get the existing orderDetails
    const orderDetails = this.shared.orderDetailsObservable.value;
    // override values
    orderDetails.shipping_cost = data.rate;
    orderDetails.shipping_method = data.name + '(' + data.shipping_method + ')';
    // update Observable
    his.shared.orderDetailsObservable.next(orderDetails);
}
```

Comment: Then  I have to move all its variable there. Isn't there an alternative to it.

Comment: I updated my anser with another approach using an Observable.